# character entities in HTML attributes

Tags: html, security

I'm studying this article: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet , and I get the idea that HTML entities which must be escaped in attribute values are different from HTML content.

But I want to know the origin, is this from some HTML spec? I can't find it, can someone point me a direction? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [my answer to *htmlspecialchars - different escaping for attributes compared to everything else?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24580477/53114) answers your question.

Comment: OK, I get it now, the Attribute value (double-quoted) state is not so different from data state. And the XSS prevention cheat sheet RULE #2 does not mean more characters must be escaped in attribute value state, it is just a suggestion to escape more characters, because a lot of people tend to forget to add quotes for attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

It's really more of a DOM issue.  But here is a jump-off point
http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/CSS.html